# Azure WebJob Indexing In Progress

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

My azure webjobs dashboard currently shows the message: "Indexing in progress"...and it tells me there are currently over 290k records left to index.

Can I improve the speed of indexing if I scale out my app service?  I'm thinking to allow for a catch-up, to perhaps scale out to, say 20 instances, and leave it like that overnight, and scale back again in the morning.

So I guess another angle of my question is...does the indexing of azure webjob invocation results happen on my own app instance's resources?  Or does this happen on some other global azure resources out of my control...in which case I just need to be patient?

Answer (score 0):

Scalling App Service won’t help, because it is process related to Azure Storage account. You will have to wait.